# How to filter a json array based on selection from react bootstrap table?

Tags: json, reactjs, filter

I am a beginner trying to learn React JS. I am loading a list of products from json using react bootstrap table. On clicking compare button, I wanted to filter the json based on user selection where 'PartNumber' is unique field for all the products.

Can any one please help how I can get the filtered list "onButtonSubmit". I am able to get the filtered products partnumbers in 'selected'. I need to filter the json array that matches the partnumbers in 'selected'. I will format the result as per my requirement.

Below is my code and this is my JSON - https://jsonblob.com/412d2ac9-2f7c-11e9-9080-8bc34cc6c646

```
import React from 'react';
import MYResult from '../json/results.json';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

class Container extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: MYResult.Products || [],
    columns: MYResult.ParametricList_Attributes || [],
    isCompareClicked: false,
    selected: []
  };

  onButtonSubmit = (row, isSelect) => {
    this.setState({ isCompareClicked: true })
    if (isSelect) {
      this.setState(() => ({
        selected: [...this.state.selected, row.PartNumber]
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(() => ({
        selected: this.state.selected.filter(x => x === row.PartNumber)
      }));
    }
    console.log("selectd is -- " + this.state.selected)
  }

  render() {
    var selectRowProp = {
      mode: "checkbox",
      clickToSelect: true,
      selected: this.state.selected,
      onSelect: this.onButtonSubmit
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonSubmit}>Compare</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <BootstrapTable keyField='PartNumber' selectRow={selectRowProp}
          data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have passed the same function to both onSelect and button click actions, but they have different operations. Also, handle all possible actions to avoid future issues

checkout this sandbox [full working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pk964xy5w0)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MYResult from "../json/results.json";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";

import "./styles.css";

class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: MYResult.Products || [],
    pristineData: MYResult.Products || [],
    columns: MYResult.ParametricList_Attributes || [],
    isCompareClicked: false,
    selected: []
  };

  onSelectClick = (row, isSelect) => {
    let modifiedRow;
    if (isSelect) {
      modifiedRow = [...this.state.selected, row.PartNumber];
    } else {
      modifiedRow = this.state.selected.filter(x => x !== row.PartNumber);
    }
    this.setState({ isCompareClicked: true, selected: modifiedRow });
  };
  onButtonClick = () => {
    const data = this.state.data;
    const selectedData = this.state.selected;
    if (selectedData.length < 2) {
      alert("atleast two data needed to compare");
      return;
    }
    let filterredData = data.filter(row =>
      selectedData.includes(row.PartNumber)
    );
    this.setState({ data: filterredData });
  };

  onSelectAll = (isSelect, rows) => {
    let newRows = isSelect ? rows.map(row => row.PartNumber) : [];
    this.setState({ selected: newRows });
  };

  onClearClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ data: state.pristineData, selected: [] }));
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    var selectRowProp = {
      mode: "checkbox",
      clickToSelect: true,
      selected: this.state.selected,
      onSelect: this.onSelectClick,
      onSelectAll: this.onSelectAll
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Compare</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClearClick}>Clear</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <BootstrapTable
          keyField="PartNumber"
          selectRow={selectRowProp}
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Instead of using button html, I wanted to create a Button Component and pass the events - compare click and clear click using props. Can you please help?